# Unit-testing Python: Mocking function calls inside function

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I have a django view like this

```
# Django view

from some_module import f2
def f1(request, version):
    # some code

    f2(**kargs)

    # more code
    return HTTPResponse(response)
```

The function f2 is in another module

```
# some_module
def f2(**kargs):
    # some code
```

The Django view is part of an API so, the request and response are in json

How do I :

1. write a unit test for this function while mocking the request
2. mock f2, which is a database based function and avoid database connections entirely

EDIT:

The database I am using is Cassandra, so I cannot use django.db

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `@mock.patch` decorator to mock `f2()` method in your unittests.

```
import mock
import some_module
from django.test import TestCase

def mocked_f2(**kargs):
    return 'Hey'

class YourTestCase(TestCase):

    @mock.patch('some_module.f2', side_effect=mocked_f2)
    def test_case(self, mocked):
        print some_module.f2()  # will print: 'Hey'
```

In this case each time you call `f2()` in your code, `mocked_f2` will be called.

Comment: What if I want to test `f1()`?

Comment: It will mock all the ``f2()`` calls, even if you do them vía ``f1()`` method

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: I reckon the code doesn't need any more explanation

Comment: @TheGeorgeous : I am reasonably new to mock but I believe you intend to test f1() function. So you are mocking all f1()'s dependency which is f2.

Answer (score 2):

django supplies some scaffolding for testing - see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#making-requests)

as for `f2()` - you can use [fixtures](http://django-testing-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fixtures.html#fixtures-in-unit-tests) to set up a db. Alternatively use [mock](https://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to supply a dummy db connection.

Comment: `f2()` simply writes some data to db. I want it mocked completely inside f1. How do I achieve that?